# Why maven requires so many options to create a hello world project,can you recommend a more dedicated build tool for Java?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process

Quoted from [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/simple-project-sect-create-simple.html):

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple \
                                         -DartifactId=simple \
                                         -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook \
                                         -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

And I also have to specify an archetype number...

It seems that maven isn't satisfied to be just a Java **build** tool,but want to control all aspect of developing...

Can someone recommend a really **dedicated** build tool for Java?

Comment: Install an IDE and create a Maven project from File/New/Project

Comment: Please, just don't use Maven, it's clearly not for you (and this will save us some ridiculous comments).

Comment: Ok, we get it, you don't like maven. You don't need to keep posting "questions" that demonstrate that you don't understand what maven was designed to achieve.

Comment: You seem oddly annoyed that Maven, a tool for managing VERSIONed ARTIFACTS, requires an ARTIFACT identifier and a VERSION number to do its work. Don't worry, I'm sure the Maven developers are implementing that 'psychic mode' any second now.

Answer (score 4):

You're misunderstanding what an archetype is, it's simply a template for creating new projects.

You don't need to use one if you don't want to, you are free to create your own pom.xml and put your source code and tests wherever you want, as long as you configure the non-standard values in your POM.

Maven doesn't "want to control all aspect of developing", it is a tool which is based around a set of best practices and standards (standard layouts, build lifecycle, projects should have versions, the idea of release vs snapshot dependencies, etc.).

You are free to not use these best practices, but to do so, you need to configure Maven for what you want.

The nice part about Maven is that when you do follow the standards, *there is often nothing to configure*. It's only when you need non-standards that you need to configure.

Answer (score 1):

A Maven project has a `groupId`, an `artifactId` and a `version` (OMG, 3 properties) so you need to set them:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple \
                          -DartifactId=simple \
                          -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

You don't like it? It's too much effort? Don't use Maven.

> It seems that maven isn't satisfied to be just a Java build tool, but want to control all aspect of developing...

Maven is more than just a build tool. It's not what you want? Don't use Maven.

> Can someone recommend a really dedicated build tool for Java?

It's the third time you ask for recommendations (first time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772966/whats-the-best-building-tool-for-java-besides-ant), second time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808051/newbie-question-about-maven)) and since you're just ignoring the answers suggesting Maven, Ant, Make, Buildr, Gradle, Gant, I would recommend **`javac`**.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate build tools: Ant (lots of configuration), Gradle (conventions again, less verbose than maven)

Maven is good if you don't want to fight its conventions.  Your example above is just asking you to define your package, jar name, and version string (all things you need to do if this code is ever going to other people).  Also you don't need to start with an archetype if you understand how to (or have a tool) to generate a pom and understand where maven wants you to put your files.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you buildr (http://buildr.apache.org/) : it's very simple to use, very powerfull and it's compatible with maven2 repos. I really love this tool.

Extract from the buildr website :

> Apache Buildr is a build system for
>   Java-based applications, including
>   support for Scala, Groovy and a
>   growing number of JVM languages and
>   tools. We wanted something that’s
>   simple and intuitive to use, so we
>   only need to tell it what to do, and
>   it takes care of the rest. But also
>   something we can easily extend for
>   those one-off tasks, with a language
>   that’s a joy to use. And of course, we
>   wanted it to be fast, reliable and
>   have outstanding dependency
>   management.